# On codepen, how do I know a pen is public?

Tags: codepen

How do I know? I was looking around on the specific pen and I did not find something that said "this pen is public or private" Thanks in advance, it's like the most basic question ever sorry [image] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgQp8.jpg

If it says this (at the bottom) https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tx3h.jpg it's public right? may someone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not own the pen:

I'm not too sure, ask the pen owner. Where did you get the link from?
Is the link quite long and look really hard to type/remember? if so it is more than likely private.

If you own the pen:

On the pen, if you click Settings in the top right

[image: Refer to this]

and then navigate to the Privacy tab

[image: Refer to this]

Comment: Before I approve your answer does that mean that  if it doesn't say Privacy Pro it's public?Because when I go to settings it doesn't show privacy pro or public, I'm on Chromium on Ubuntu 20.04 by the way, does that have something to do with it?

Comment: Are you a pro user on CodePen? If so, click on the tab and it will more than likely bring up a modal with a switch on it. You can determine if it is private by the state of the switch.

Comment: I'm not a Pro user, I want to upload a screenshot on a comment how do I do that?

Comment: Upload it to Imgur and link it using the format: [link](URL). I recommend editing your original question if you are going to append some images.

Comment: Done, it's in the question (the screenshot)

Comment: I edited my answer. From the image, I can see you do not own the pen.

Comment: https://imgur.com/oqw4GIp Hey friends, if it says that it's public right? at the bottom